# How can I execute two shell functions at the same time?

Tags: linux, string, function, shell, output

I have written a shell script with functions which output some ASCII animation. I would like to execute two of these functions at the same time but have them display the art one under the other, for example:

```
function_one(){
clear
printf %s '
______________
||__________||

'
sleep 1
tput home
printf %s '
______________
||__________||
      ||
      ||
      ||

'
sleep 1
tput home
printf %s '
______________
||__________||
      ||
      ||
      ||
||‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾||
‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾
'
}
```

imagine this function continues to print more ASCII letters but in the same set of 7 lines it has already taken then underneath this I want another function to start:

```
function_two(){
sleep 10
printf %b "this is an example\r"
printf %b "this is more example\r"
printf %b "and some more\r"
}
```

function_two sleeps for a while to allow function_one to take all the space it needs but starts before function_one has finished and displays its output below function_one.
Is this possible? I have tried piping the functions, eg:

```
function_one | function_two
```

but this only seems to execute function_two.
Sorry, this isn't the easiest thing to explain but I hope you can understand.
Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Advanced control of where on a display to print isn't something you can do trivially. You need to specify where to draw/etc.

Pipes send the output from one command to another command (so `function_two` there gets on its standard input the output from `function_one` which isn't at all what you want).

If you just don't want `function_two` to wait for `function_one` to finish put `function_one` in the background with `&`.

```
function_one &
function_two
```

But if `function_one` isn't done printing this isn't going to work how you want it to.